# What is the most cost-effective way of synchronising Adwords information to local database

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am working on Adwords API to get information about campaigns, adgroups, criteria, ads and then keywords and store them in local database. There could be many updates directly on Adwords Portal on a day to day basis. But I need my application to reflect all those updates in my local database as well. What is the most cost-effective way to achieve this and How?

Comment: start writing some code? unclear what your actully asking.

Comment: No, I don't need any code. Just wanted to know the approach. I need my database to synchronise with the users adwords data. All I wanted to know is best approach to do this. For example, I can check if there are any new campaigns, insert them to database and for each campaign, check if there is any change and if there is any, update it in local database. But, with this approach, we need to make many calls to API, so it is expensive. Other approach would be, delete complete data and reinsert that data again. But this could eventually increase which is again making many calls means more money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what fields you are interested in storing in your local database. One approach is to run AdWords API reports to download and load values into the local database. The plus side is that reports are free. The downside is that reports do not expose all fields.  The other approach is to run CustomerSyncService to figure out what exactly changed during a period and make AdWords API calls to download specific objects. That will cost you money, but it is better than downloading the entire account using AdWords API calls.

See the following links:

Reporting basics: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/guides/reporting.html
Report types: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/reports.html
CustomerSyncService: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CustomerSyncService.html
Using CustomerSyncService: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201109/AccountManagement/GetAccountChanges.php

Also, if you have more questions related to AdWords API, I recommend asking them on the official forum at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/. The forum is active and AdWords API team members and official library maintainers regularly answer questions on the forum.